# Lemoon CMS - Switch Language

Tags: content-management-system, lemoon

How do I switch between languages in Lemoon CMS? 
I have found out how to fins all languages and so on, but how do I actually change to another language?

A collegue gave me old code and there I was supposed to create a link for each language like "~/~2/" where "2" is the languageID. This doesn't seams to work.

Is the another way?

I'm running Mindroute.Core: 4.5.1.196, Mindroute.Lemoon: 4.5.1.196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create a binding (map a URL and/or path) for each language/site. You do this under manage->sites. For instance www.mysite.com for the English and www.mysite.se for the Swedish versions of a site.

Then it is simply a matter of using the Site.Url() method to create links to the different languages/sites.